# How to use System.Windows in Mono / MonoDevelop?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, monodevelop, rect

I'm trying to use the Rect structure from System.Windows in MonoDevelop, but I can't find System.Windows in the packages list when I try to add a reference to it.  There are lots of things like System.Windows.Controls.... and System.Windows.Forms... but not System.Windows by itself.  How do I get access to Rect in MonoDevelop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Rect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.rect.aspx) structure is defined in WindowsBase.dll (if targetting .NET 4).  You would need to add a reference to that assembly to get access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try
    Android.Graphics.Rect

its defined in Mono.Android.dll, there is no implementation to Windows.Forms.Rect under mono